# Java выборка из двумерного массива

Tags: java

Сделал метод, для выборки из двумерного массива. В метод приходит двумерный массив `C` и элемент для сравнения `selectedItem`
Проверка идет по втором элементу каждого подмассива. Как только нахожу совпадение в родительском массиве записываю его в дочерний. Количество строк дочернего массива выводится верно, но все данные выводятся как null. То есть, метод верно выстраивает массив, но не переносит данные из родитеkьского в дочерний. Не могу разобраться почему, может кто подскажет?

```
 public String[][] selectContr(String[][] c, String selectedItem) {

    int rows = c.length;
    int columns = c[0].length;
    String contractor[][] = null;

    int coorect = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        if (selectedItem.equals(c[j][2])) {
            coorect = coorect + 1; // Высчитываю кол-во подмассивов в дочерний двумерный массив.

        }
    }

    contractor = new String[coorect][columns];
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        if (selectedItem.equals(c[j][2])) {
            for (int n = 0; n == columns; n++) {
                
                for (int c1 = 0; c1 == coorect; c1++) {

                    contractor[c1][n] = c[j][n];
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return contractor;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        for (int n = 0; n == columns; n++) {
                          ^^
            for (int c = 0; c == coorect; c++) {
                              ^^
```

Это называется "условие *продолжения* цикла".

---

```
contractor[c][n] = c[j][n];
           ^       ^
```

Не хватает букв?

Comment: Перепечатывал вручную, массив имеет более длинное название, лень писать тут было. Сейчас исправлю

Comment: @Drop так вам уже указали на ошибку. она не в "названии", а в "цикле".  for (int n = 0; n == columns; n++)  n=0. n = columns ? нет. цикл закончил свою работу и больше не работает.

Comment: @Wlad когда писал комент, ответ был без этого
спасибо